# nexus 4 bootloader only

Tags: ubuntu-touch, data-recovery, nexus-4

after trying to flash Ubuntu on my nexus 4 ,the process was some how interrupted and my phone is unusable except for the boot-loader.is there any one who can help with this?

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the last output of the process?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do would probably be to start fresh. There are instruction for restoring stock Android at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install#Restoring_Android

Once you get back to a stock Android, you can retry and make sure it doesn't get interrupted this time. :)